# Nodejs - sort an array of object with another array

Tags: node.js, underscore.js

Is it possible to sort or re-arrange the json object with another array set

Here is the JSON object with url key

```
var items-array = [
    {
    "_source":{
    "Edition":{
    "Values":{
    "title":"new featured parallex",
    "indexContent":" new "
    }
    },
    "url":"/demo-inline-component-capability/demo-of-featured-parallex"
    },
    "isPromoted":true
    },
    {
    "_source":{
    "Edition":{
    "Values":{
    "title":"demo of event careers",
    "description":"careers",
    "indexContent":" careers demo urrent"
    }
    },
    "url":"/demo-inline-component-capability/demo-of-event-card"
    },
    "isPromoted":true
    },
    {
    "_source":{
    "Edition":{
    "Values":{
    "title":"reference event cards",
    "indexContent":" reference event cards <cmp id=\"jvcbt0if\" class=\"cmp\" contenteditable=\"false\"> orange"
    }
    },
    "url":"/demo-inline-component-capability/demo-of-ref-event-card"
    },
    "isPromoted":true
    },
    {
    "_source":{
    "Edition":{
    "Values":{
    "title":"demo of video playlists",
    "indexContent":" demo "
    }
    },
    "url":"/demo-inline-component-capability/demo-of-video-playlist"
    },
    "isPromoted":true
    },
    {
    "_source":{
    "Edition":{
    "Values":{
    "title":"demo of data point set careers",
    "description":"careers",
    "indexContent":" careers demo of data point set red"
    }
    },
    "url":"/demo-inline-component-capability/demo-of-data-point-set"
    },
    "sort":[
    1555320208440
    ]
    },
    {
    "_source":{
    "Edition":{
    "Values":{
    "title":"Xfinity TV’sa Lunar New Year collection is a celebration of the vast contributions the Asian American community makes to entertainment across comcast careers",
    "description":"mobile name",
    "indexContent":" mobile name "
    }
    },
    "url":"/lunar-festival"
    },
    "sort":[
    1551093922066
    ]
    }
    ]
```

To match with sorting array of url

```
var sortingArr = ["/demo-inline-component-capability/demo-of-video-playlist","/demo-inline-component-capability/demo-of-featured-parallel","/demo-inline-component-capability/demo-of-ref-event-card","/demo-inline-component-capability/demo-of-event-card"]
```

Unfortunately, I don’t have any IDs to keep track on. I would need to priority the items-array to match the sortingArr as close as possible.

Any idea how this can be done.

Comment: So just to be clear, you want to sort `items_array` by `sortingArr`? (none of your code is valid btw)

Comment: @James did my answer help solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The code below will output a new array `newArr` with whatever it finds in the order provided.  It will not include any items that aren't in the `sortingArr`.

```
var newArr = [];

sortingArr.forEach(s => {
    var i = itemsArray.find(o => {
        return o["_source"]["url"] === s;
    })

    if(i != null) {
        newArr.push(i);
    }
});

newArr.forEach(o => {
    console.log(o);
});
```

Also, the `sortingArr` is malformed.  It should be:

```
var sortingArr = ["/demo-inline-component-capability/demo-of-video-playlist","/demo-inline-component-capability/demo-of-featured-parallel","/demo-inline-component-capability/demo-of-ref-event-card","/demo-inline-component-capability/demo-of-event-card"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have come with this O(n) solution 
you can create an object having keys as the url  and value as list of objects corresponding to the URL 
Then based on the sorting order URL  present in the sortArray you can iterate over the sort array and get the corresponding list of objects in the object and merge them to get the final array

```
function sortItem(items_array, sortUrl) {
    let urlMap = {}
    for (item of items_array) {
        let url = item._source.url
        if (!urlMap.hasOwnProperty(url)) {
            urlMap[url] = []
        }
        urlMap[url].push(item)
    }
    let finalList =[]
    for (url of sortUrl){
        if(urlMap.hasOwnProperty(url)){
        let itemList = urlMap[url]
        finalList = finalList.concat(itemList)
        }
    }

    return finalList
}
```

sortUrl is the list of urls to sort the items_array

```
var sortingArr = ["/demo-inline-component-capability/demo-of-video-playlist","/demo-inline-component-capability/demo-of-featured-parallel","/demo-inline-component-capability/demo-of-ref-event-card","/demo-inline-component-capability/demo-of-event-card"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) for this

```
const sorted = items_array.sort((a, b) => {
  // take index of URL from sorting array
  const ai = sortingArr.findIndex(x => a._source.url === x);
  const bi = sortingArr.findIndex(x => b._source.url === x);

  // handle edge case where lower URL is sortable and other isn't
  if (ai === -1 && bi > ai) return 1; 
  // handle edge case where higher URL is sortable and other isn't
  if (bi === -1 && ai > bi) return -1; 
  // handle all other scenarios
  return ai - bi;
});
```

**Example**

```js
var items_array = [
{
"_source":{
"Edition":{
"Values":{
"title":"new featured parallex",
"indexContent":" new "
}
},
"url":"/demo-inline-component-capability/demo-of-featured-parallex"
},
"isPromoted":true
},
{
"_source":{
"Edition":{
"Values":{
"title":"demo of event careers",
"description":"careers",
"indexContent":" careers demo urrent"
}
},
"url":"/demo-inline-component-capability/demo-of-event-card"
},
"isPromoted":true
},
{
"_source":{
"Edition":{
"Values":{
"title":"reference event cards",
"indexContent":" reference event cards <cmp id=\"jvcbt0if\" class=\"cmp\" contenteditable=\"false\"> orange"
}
},
"url":"/demo-inline-component-capability/demo-of-ref-event-card"
},
"isPromoted":true
},
{
"_source":{
"Edition":{
"Values":{
"title":"demo of video playlists",
"indexContent":" demo "
}
},
"url":"/demo-inline-component-capability/demo-of-video-playlist"
},
"isPromoted":true
},
{
"_source":{
"Edition":{
"Values":{
"title":"demo of data point set careers",
"description":"careers",
"indexContent":" careers demo of data point set red"
}
},
"url":"/demo-inline-component-capability/demo-of-data-point-set"
},
"sort":[
1555320208440
]
},
{
"_source":{
"Edition":{
"Values":{
"title":"Xfinity TV’sa Lunar New Year collection is a celebration of the vast contributions the Asian American community makes to entertainment across comcast careers",
"description":"mobile name",
"indexContent":" mobile name "
}
},
"url":"/lunar-festival"
},
"sort":[
1551093922066
]
}
]

var sortingArr = [
  "/demo-inline-component-capability/demo-of-video-playlist",
  "/demo-inline-component-capability/demo-of-featured-parallel",
  "/demo-inline-component-capability/demo-of-ref-event-card",
  "/demo-inline-component-capability/demo-of-event-card"
];

console.log('BEFORE');
for (var x of items_array) {
  console.log(x._source.url);
}

const sorted = items_array.sort((a, b) => {
  // take index of URL from sorting array
  const ai = sortingArr.findIndex(x => a._source.url === x);
  const bi = sortingArr.findIndex(x => b._source.url === x);

  // handle edge case where lower URL is sortable and other isn't
  if (ai === -1 && bi > ai) return 1; 
  // handle edge case where higher URL is sortable and other isn't
  if (bi === -1 && ai > bi) return -1; 
  // handle all other scenarios
  return ai - bi;
});

console.log('AFTER');
for (var y of sorted) {
  console.log(y._source.url);
}
```